# How can I view a list of the sites in an Azure Website Hosting Plan?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-web-app-service

We have set up 40 sites on 4 different hosting plans. One of the plans has very high memory use even though it only has 9 sites, but I can't see which 9 sites this plan contains!

In addition, though I can see the overall memory use for the plan, is there any way to tell which site is using all the memory?

Comment: I think your question will better fit on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps, though I'm a programmer and there are far more questions tagged azure and azure-websites on stackoverflow.

Comment: You can see websites by hosting plan in the [preview portal](http://portal.azure.com)

Comment: I can't. I can see resource group lists but not hosting plan lists. Unfortunately we have been putting our sites in one resource group and splitting sites across plans as required for capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Two part answer:

1. To see which sites are under which plan, browse to the Web Hosting Plan in the preview portal (portal.azure.com).
2. To see the memory used by a given site you can go to that site's kudu portal (located at http://.scm.azurewebsites.net) and log in with your Microsoft credentials. Click on the Process Explorer tab. Now you'll see all the processes running in that site and exactly how much memory each of them is taking.

You can also see memory usage in the preview portal but the kudu portal will give you better details as to what's going on

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the kudu portal - what a great tip I never knew this existed!! As for the sites under a plan, I still can't find a list. When I click on the plan in the new portal, it displays the resource group. We have 3 of our plans in the same resource group so this gives me a list of 36 sites, so I still can't work out how to see which 9 sites are in the plan. Thanks for your help.